# Iterating a 2d array and then return the max value of each sub-list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to loop a list of lists, and then returning the max values of each sublist.

for example: `list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`
What I want is a new list with the values: `[3,6,9]`

I'm not allowed to use any imports or the `map()`, `max()` builtins.
I thought in sorting every sublist and then returning the last index, but I don't know how to code this.

Comment: Did you try using some `for` loops and `if` statements?

Comment: If I give you a single list, can you find the max value by hand, by looking at each value one at a time? Can you describe how you would do it?

Comment: sorting a list to get the max is just innefficient. Also naming a list `list` just shadows the built in function [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), which is a bad idea.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using the `max` function, this could fairly straightforwardly be done as a list comprehension:

```
[max(sublist) for sublist in list]
```

If you can't use the `max` built-in directly, there are several ways of doing it manually using other functions:

Sorting each sublist, as you suggested in the question:

```
[sorted(sublist)[-1] for sublist in list]
```

(`-1` means the last element of the list)

Or just manually implementing `max` using a `for` loop and a `if` statement:

```
def custom_max(sublist):
     maximum = None
     for element in sublist:
         if maximum is None or element > maximum:
             maximum = element
     return maximum

[custom_max(sublist) for sublist in list]
```

The `custom_max` function works by keeping a running maximum and comparing each element of the list to that maximum.

Comment: Thank you sir, I actually implemented my own max function. Sorry for answer you this late.
What a did was: I implemented 2 functions, max and min.


def max(my_list):

    max = my_list[0]
    for i in my_list:
        if i > max:
            max = i
    return max

def min(my_list):
    miv = list[0]
    for i in list:
        if i<min:
            min = i
    return min